# AndroidManifest.xml tags

Tags: javascript, java, android, xml

I'm trying to update my app in Google play, but when I do I get this error

"You uploaded an APK file whose AndroidManifest.xml contains multiple tag entries. There must be only one."

This is my AndroidManifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.xxx.xxx.xxxxxxx" platformBuildVersionCode="23" platformBuildVersionName="6.0-2438415">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RESTART_PACKAGES"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <application android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name" android:largeHeap="true" android:name="lockscreen.gpaddy.com.lockscreen.util.MyApplication" android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="lockscreen.gpaddy.com.lockscreen.activity.SettingActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:label="@string/title_activity_lock" android:name="lockscreen.gpaddy.com.lockscreen.LockActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"/>
        <activity android:excludeFromRecents="true" android:label="@string/title_activity_lock2" android:launchMode="singleInstance" android:name="lockscreen.gpaddy.com.lockscreen.activity.LockHasPasscode" android:noHistory="true" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:theme="@style/AppTheme"/>
        <activity android:excludeFromRecents="true" android:label="@string/title_activity_lock2" android:launchMode="singleInstance" android:name="lockscreen.gpaddy.com.lockscreen.activity.LockNoPasscode" android:noHistory="true" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:theme="@style/AppTheme"/>
        <activity android:name="lockscreen.gpaddy.com.lockscreen.activity.ChangePassCodeActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"/>
        <activity android:name="lockscreen.gpaddy.com.lockscreen.activity.DisablePass" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"/>
        <activity android:name="lockscreen.gpaddy.com.lockscreen.activity.PaddyGetBackgroundActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"/>
        <service android:name="lockscreen.gpaddy.com.lockscreen.service.MyService"/>
        <receiver android:enabled="true" android:exported="true" android:name="lockscreen.gpaddy.com.lockscreen.broadcast.BootComlepeReceiver">
            <intent-filter android:priority="9999">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <service android:enabled="true" android:exported="false" android:name="com.ironsource.mobilcore.MobileCoreReport" android:process=":mcServiceProcess"/>
        <receiver android:enabled="true" android:name="com.ironsource.mobilcore.InstallationTracker" android:process=":installationTracker"/>
        <activity android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode" android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent"/>
        <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.purchase.InAppPurchaseActivity" android:theme="@style/Theme.IAPTheme"/>
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
        <activity android:exported="false" android:name="com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"/>
        <meta-data android:name="com.android.vending.derived.apk.id" android:value="1"/>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Could you paste your merged Manifest? https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manifest-merge.html#inspect_the_merged_manifest_and_find_conflicts

Comment: ï'm using apktool what triggered this problem ?